# Why $E=mc^2$ formula does not include time?

Tags: mass-energy, time-evolution

For $E=mc^2$ formula, if an object of mass $m$ kg goes with speed of light (in theory), it transforms energy according to $E=mc^2$ but if there is no time complexity this will not happen. So I think this formula (and others) should depend on time but there is no time variable on this formula why ?

Comment: You have misunderstood the equation. The energy $E=mc^2$ is the energy corresponding to the rest mass i.e. it is the total energy when the object is at rest. If the object is moving with some momentum $p$ the energy increases to $E = \sqrt{p^2c^2 + m^2c^4}$. As the velocity approaches $c$ the energy becomes infinite.

Comment: An object need not travel at the speed of light for its energy to be $ mc^2 $. The formula states that mass is equivalent to energy. In many areas of physics, saying that there is mass at some point is equivalent to saying that there is energy at that point.

Comment: Physics is not opinion.
$E=mc^2$ means something with mass 'm' has energy mc^2.
 E=mc^2 has nothing to do with velocity.

Comment: @Paul I think opinions are important for physic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no transformation of energy when an object moves at a constant velocity. If this velocity is non-zero, then the equation reads $E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+(mc^2)^2}$. So in truth, the famous equation $E=mc^2$ is just a special case of the more general formula stated above.

None of this, however, alters the fact, that there is no time scale involved, as you suggest should be. But why should the system of this (free) object change over time, especially when we talk about a conserved quantity (the energy)?

Time plays only a role when interactions are introduced. See for example the [Navier-Stokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equation which describes fluid dynamics. There you have a time dependent term $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ which describes the change of velocity.

Comment: I see but in my opinion, If any energy will occur then it needs time.

Comment: @Ozn Ozi What do you mean "Energy will occur"? Energy is not a phenomenon.

Comment: @HadrianEvan I mean you have energy to press keyboard but this will happen only if there is time, if there is no time, just this energy there is. And I see that can show that energy with E=mc^2. But if I want to transformation of energy, time required.

Comment: @Ozn Ozi You are right in saying that transfer of energy will take time, but time is not required for the energy to just exist. $ E = mc^2 $ is not about using energy to do work, but showing that energy is present.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely misunderstanding what the equation means. All the equation above says, is that an object of mass $m$, has an energy content $E$ equal to $mc^2$ where $c^2$ is the square of speed of light.

The equation is **not** describing how energy changes/converted at all. It just gives the energy *content* of an object.